# Is it needed to define IEEEtran class in beamer also for bibliography? If yes how could we define two classes?

Tags: beamer

Is it needed to define IEEEtran class in beamer also for bibliography? If yes how could we define two classes ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please try to clarify your question? Do you want to create a `beamer` presentation with a specific citation style? What do you mean with "define IEEEtran class in beamer also for bibliography"?

Comment: I am using Beamer for my presentation , now stuck at bibliography.

Answer (score 1):

There is a LaTeX document class called `IEEEtran` (it's set up up in a file called `IEEEtran.cls`), and there is a BibTeX bibliography style called `IEEEtran` (set up in a file called `IEEEtran.bst`).

In a LaTeX document, the selected document class appears in the argument of `\documentclass`, while the selected bibliography style appears in the argument of `\bibliographystyle`.

The IEEEtran document class and the IEEEtran bibliography style may be employed independently of each other. That said, they're frequently used together, presumably because some journals *require* authors to do so.

One can definitely *not* use two or more LaTeX document classes simultaneously. (Don't believe me? Just try compiling a LaTeX document with two or more `\documentclass` statements...) Since you appear to be using the `beamer` document class, you cannot use the `IEEEtran` class as well.

You are free to use just about any bibliography style that strikes your fancy with the `beamer` document class -- including, you guessed it, the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.

Comment: Yes m using \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} but its not working

Comment: @user202178 - Sorry, but the claim "it's not working" is so vague as to be useless. *What exactly* isn't working? Do you get LaTeX and/or BibTeX error  or warning messages? If so, what do they say? Please be specific.